# Is it possible to add a having clause in JPA query that returns custom entity?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following jpa query (I eliminated non relevant info from it):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new SomeEntitySummary(et.id, count(ret.id)) " +
        "FROM SomeEntity et left join SomeRelatedEntity ret on ( ... ) " +
        "WHERE ... " +
        "group by et.id"
    )
```

It returns a custom object as a result and not the entity.

Is it possible to include a having clause in it?

The sql equivalent works and would look something like:

```
select et.id,count(ret.id)
from someentity et
left join somerelatedentity ld on (...)
group by et.id
**having count(ret.id) between 1 and 100**
```

Is it possible to write this in the jpa query? I have not managed to find any relevant examples yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. According to the hibernate documentation (see the [15.51. Group by](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-group-by) section).

> In a grouped query, the where clause applies to the non-aggregated values (essentially it determines whether rows will make it into the aggregation). The `HAVING` clause also restricts results, but it operates on the aggregated values.
>
> The `HAVING` clause follows the same rules as the `WHERE` clause and is also made up of predicates. `HAVING` is applied after the groupings and aggregations have been done, while the `WHERE` clause is applied before.

So, you can add having clause to your first query in the following way:

```sql
SELECT new SomeEntitySummary(et.id, count(ret.id))
FROM SomeEntity et left join SomeRelatedEntity ret on ( ... )
WHERE ... 
group by et.id
having count(ret.id) between 1 and 100
```